# apache2.4 with lua scripts: LuaMapHandler causes config syntax error

Tags: apache, lua, apache-modules

I'm trying to run a simple `lua` script on my Apache server (`version 2.4.23`).

I followed these [instructions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_lua.html#luamaphandler) and added the next line to my `apache2.conf`:

```
LuaMapHandler / /path/to/lua/script.lua my_lua_handler
```

when restarting my server I'm getting this output:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command 'LuaMapHandler', perhaps misspelled or defined by included in the server configuration
```

As far as I read the `mod_lua` is already available from `version 2.3`
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to [load](http://webauth.stanford.edu/manual/mod/mod_lua.html) the module:

```
LoadModule lua_module modules/mod_lua.so
```

and/or enable it using

```
a2enmod lua
```